# Handling error in ui-routers resolve function? (aka $stateChangeError) Passing data to error state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Inside my `Angular` application I handle routes/states via `ui-router`. If everything works - it is great. But what is a *good* way to handle errors occurring inside `resolve` functions?

My current solution:
I have a to dedicated `error` state (similar to the common `404.html`). Which looks like this:

```
// inside config()
.state('error', {
  url: '/error',
  controller: 'ErrorCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'error.html' // displays an error message
})
```

If an error occurs inside `resolve` I catch it via the broadcasted `$stateChangeError` in m `run` function:

```
angular.module('myModule').run(function($state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('error');
  });
});
```

This works, **but** I want to change my error message inside my `'error.html'` dependent on the error. I don't want to pollute the `$rootScope` and I want to do it in a `ui-router`'esk way.

My current solution uses `$stateParams` to the error data to my `error` state, but I have to use JSONified query params for this and get a very ugly URL:

```
// inside config()
.state('error', {
  url: '/error?data&status&config', // accept these three params
  controller: 'ErrorCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'error.html' // displays an error message
})

angular.module('myModule').run(function($state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('error', JSON.stringify(error)); // error has data, status and config properties
  });
});
```

**Question**
Is there a different way how I can pass the `error` object to my `error` state without uglifying my URL? (Note: My `error` object is complex and not just a simple string.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could pass data through a service, that you should access in your error controller or in onEnter method of error state.

Or you could "enrich" your error state. Maybe it's NOT the angular way, but what I mean is:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $state.get('error').error = { code: 123, description: 'Exception stack trace' }
  return $state.go('error');
});
```

And in your error state config:

```
.state('error', {
    url: 'error',
    resolve: {
        errorObj: [function () {
            return this.self.error;
        }]
    },
    controller: 'ErrorCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'error.html' // displays an error message
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 27):

A strategy that worked for me is to have the `resolve` functions return a rejected promise with the **error object**:

```
$stateProvider.state('needs_authentication', {
    url: '/auth',
    resolve: {
        user: function ($q, authService) {
            if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                ...
            }
            else {
                var errorObject = { code: 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED' };
                return $q.reject(errorObject);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This lets your `$stateChangeError` function be able to handle specific error conditions:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (angular.isObject(error) && angular.isString(error.code)) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED':
                // go to the login page
                $state.go('login');
                break;
            default:
                // set the error object on the error state and go there
                $state.get('error').error = error;
                $state.go('error');
        }
    }
    else {
        // unexpected error
        $state.go('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Much cleaner and idiomatic approach.

Comment: Where do you put $rootScope.$on?

Comment: @Benny $rootScope.$on goes inside a run() function, for some more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation

Comment: @Miller perfect! Thanks for the tip this solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/36427578/2515275

Comment: @Miller  have been doing the exact same thing. Except I don't want url to change when there is an error, I just want the error page to show. I tried $state.go('error', null , {location: false}); which works if it is the first page load. But when you click on a link that takes you to this error state, it does not change url to target states url. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @gomyes my normal strategy for doing this is to have your error view outside of the angular-ui-router system, this might be a top level div that fills the screen and only becomes visible when an error occurs. So instead of $state.go() you might use $rootState.$broadcast() to broadcast an error event that causes the your error div/view to reveal itself

Comment: Clean and nice approach, but if you use $state.go() in $stateChangeError handler, you need to add event.preventDefault() to prevent ui-router from reverting the URL to the previous valid location.

Comment: Not to be a nit-picker, just for good code cleanliness  :) ; there should be a `break;` at the end of the default clause.   But a very good clean solution.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the whole url: option and replace this with just a params: option.

> ```
>                 .state('error', {
>                     abstract: false,
>                     templateUrl: templateFor('error'),
>                     controller: controllerFor('error'),
>                     params: { 'error': 'An error has occurred' },
>                     resolve: {
>                         error: [
>                             '$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
>                                 return  $stateParams.error;
>                             }
>                         ]
>                     }
>                 })
> ```

Now there is no ugly url. and the controller can get the error as a parameter.