# Angular js - resolve and run() order of execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, config

Thanks to this answer [AngularJS app.run() documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation) i can see the order in which modules are ran by Angular, my question is:

if I have:

```
app.config(function () {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        ....
        resolve: {
            // something to resolve
        }
    });
});

app.run(function () {
    // something to run
});
```

Will `run()` be executed before the routeProvider `resolve:{}` is resolved?

Comment: someone playing with -1 button like a kid

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At least in my experiments, yes the resolve is run after `app.run`.

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cg54/) you can see the calling order I got was:

1. app config
2. app run
3. directive setup
4. directive compile
5. app controller
6. directive link
7. ** Data resolve called **
8. new route's controller

As you can see in the fiddle, I checked this by using a `console.log` function as the value of a property of the object handed to `resolve`:

```
resolve: {
            data: function() {
              console.log('Data resolve called');
            }
         }
```

You can use this same approach in your code to check when `routeProvider` begins checking the dependencies.