# Angular: app.run() mandatory or optional?

Tags: angularjs

app.run is supposed to be Angular's silbling to a Java `main` function. But is it mandatory or optional?

See also: [AngularJS app.run() documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation)

Comment: it's optional, there are many cases where you won't need it. There is no such thing as a 'main' function in angularjs.

Comment: Just to clarify, *app.run()* does not run or start up your application, its just as @TomA said below.

Answer (score 1):

It is optional. Run blocks are effectively used for tasks that need to run before any other part of the app is injected or instantiated. If you don't have any of those requirements, you don't need a `run` block :)

Source - I've maybe written one, maybe two, `run` blocks for the multitude of angular projects I've worked on.

Edit: Run blocks won't run before EVERYTHING, they will run after config and service instantiation. Thanks to the comment below for pointing that out.

Comment: Run block runs after all config phase is complete and the services are setup for DI. It's not guaranteed that it would run before other parts.