# how to use stateprovider in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

Trying to use a state router in angular:

```
var app =angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.router']);

app.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.tabs = [
        { title:'Orders', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
        { title:'Awaiting settlement', content:'Dynamic content 2' },
        { title:'Complete', content:'Dynamic content 3' }
    ];

});

app.config(function($stateProvider,$state) {
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('orders', {
            templateUrl: '../partials/orders.html',
            controller: 'ordersCtrl'

        });

    $state.go('orders');
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module WIP due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.run` in app module

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used
>   to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.
>
> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the service have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

```
app.run(function($state) { 
    $state.go('orders');
});

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('orders', {
       url : '/orders',
       templateUrl: '../partials/orders.html',
        controller: 'ordersCtrl'
   });
});
```

[**SEE MORE In SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation)

Answer (score 1):

> `provider` are only accessible in config phase with `Provider` post-fix Like you want to access `$state` provider then it would be `$stateProvider`

You can not access `$state` in config phase, `$state` is `provider`

Removing `$state` from function will fix your issue.

For re redirecting to default state I'd prefer you to use `$urlRouterProvider` & mention your `URL` in that, that will redirect to `/orders` when `url` doesn't match any `state` which makes more sense.

**Config**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('orders', {
            url: '/order',//just for demonstration
            templateUrl: '../partials/orders.html',
            controller: 'ordersCtrl'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/orders');
});
```

Comment: @Pindakaas could I ask why you don;t preferring `$urlRouterProvider`?