# Call a function on every template/controller onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just a made a function for my app that checks the users info. I created this in my authentication controller in the `$rootScope`

My problem is that now, I have to manually call that function in all the controllers that I have.

There must be a way to automatically call that on all pages when the page loads.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the ui-router?

Comment: Yes. @AndreKreienbring

Comment: You mean trigger it on application load or when a given range of views get's compiled?

Comment: @ChrisHermut I Need it whenever I reload any  page.

Comment: So yea on application load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at $location service.

After url changes it broadcasts '$locationChangeSuccess' so from there you can just use $scope.$on();

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Update: After reading your comment you might be better of using .run

[AngularJS app.run() documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation)

Comment: Is the run section of a module really called every time any controller is loaded or reloaded?

Comment: No it's not. See here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. .run is executed after injector is created and it happens once after application starts.

Answer (score 0):

To call a certain function every time a controller loads there is this receipt:
1) Define the function on the $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.myFunction = function(param1, param2){
  //do your stuff
}
```

and then in every controller just use it like this:
`myFunction(what, ever);`

This way the function will even be called when the controller is reloaded.

Comment: Yea. I was just wondering what you do if you have lots of controllers. It seems pretty annoying to copy and paste it 100 times.

Comment: At least I don't know of any other way to achieve this.