# Using Angular to authenticate users API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, restful-authentication, pardot

I am building a web application in Angular ( Im new to Angular).

I building a form to pass new user info to the third party software via API end point.

to post data I need to pass `name(new user)` `email(new user)` `user_key(mine)` and `api_key (changes evry hour)`

To get the new `api_key` I need to Post

```
POST: https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3
message body: email=<email>&password=<password>&user_key=<user_key>
```

and this returns

```
<rsp stat="ok" version="1.0">
    <api_key><api_key here></api_key>
</rsp>
```

Once I have the new Key I can pass it with the form post to post data.

**Question**

I think Ill need to have a function that runs before the Posting of data that dose the post to get the new `api_key`and changes the `api_key` variable on my new user post.

so the main question is how do I do this with angular, I have added my current post controller bellow that post the new user data.

**My controller**

```
// submit button controller POST
// =============================================================================
FirstModule.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.processForm = function (Fname, Lname, email) {
        var data = {
            Fname: $scope.formData.Fname,
            Lname: $scope.formData.Lname,
            email: $scope.formData.email,
            api_key: 'changes every hr', //needs to be dynamic
            user_key: 'my key'
        };

//Call the services
        $http.post('https://some api.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/create', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";

        }, function (response) {
            $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Failed";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
    };
});
```

**My form**

```
<form name="myForm" id="signup-form" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"
                  ng-submit="processForm()"
                  ng-click="postdata(formData)">

                <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
            </form>
```

So this part is Ok, but how do I run a function before this runs so I get the latest `api_key` ? and more importantly how can I do it safe ?

The API is [Pardot](http://developer.pardot.com/)

For security should I place all; API request on a backed script maybe node ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use app.run() and write the function in that. app.run() will always run before your controller. Here is one link you can check [AngularJS app.run() documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation)

Comment: Thanks ill look into this, So i build a function to get the api_key save then insert that api_key in my post controller ?

Comment: Yes, One more important thing to notice here is if you are maintaining an user session in your app then you can store that in the session and write a method in your app.run() like $scope.sessionDetails();