# initAutocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use Place Autocomplete using AngularJS, and I receive:

> initAutocomplete is not a function

I searched for similar problems, nothing helped to solve the problem.

This is my code:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('FirstCont', function ($scope, $http) {

console.log("OUT");

$scope.slctd_lng = 'SDF'
$scope.slct_att = 'SD'

window.initAutocomplete = function () {

    console.log("entered INIT");

    $scope.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{ types: ['geocode'] });
    $scope.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', $scocpe.fillInAddress);
}


$scope.fillInAddress = function () {
    var place = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace();

}


$scope.geolocate = function() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });

            $scope.autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}});
```

And in my html file, I included:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDsMQs29oSTadTMQI8Qy-VudC4N-kPvCpU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Note: I can see: (in the html file)

```
$scope.slctd_lng = 'SDF'
$scope.slct_att = 'SD'
```

but I did not receive 'OUT' in the console!!

Thanks

Comment: Try declaring initAutocomplete  on your $scope and inoke that function

Comment: the init function should run before loading the page so using $scope not solving the problem (I tried before)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function inside of your controller.
`$scope.initAutocomplete = function () ...;` and then use it as $scope.initAutocomplete() or in HTML simply initAutocomplete()

Comment: I tried to declare it as $scope.. but this will not work, although this way I can see OUT in the log..
the init function should be run before loading the page, which means before running the controller, so it will not help if I use $scope

Comment: @O.Dacca if you need to have it before, then you have got your answer. Angular controller is not a place for it. You may find this link useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I didn't change anything..
I rewrite the the init function and it works now, maybe it was a typing error.

thanks