# show image for a time, before displaying the real webpage

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, loading, onload

I have a webpage, made with AngularJS.
I want to display a image (fullscreen) for 5 seconds, before the user sees the real page.
Like a kind of loading screen

According to this: [window.onload does not work in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059284/window-onload-does-not-work-in-angularjs) its not possible to use window.onload.

with some research i found the following functions:
- ng-Show
- ng-Hide
- ng-init (article)

but i have no idea how i would do this..?

Sorry if this is a bad question, im quite new.

Comment: Please don't do that, it's annoying.

Comment: there is the [ngCloak directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak) that allows you to hide your template code till angular is ready to compile it. It has an example of use on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [angular-fullscreen](https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen) directive for fullscreen

**angular-fullscreen-** is an AngularJS service and a directive to quickly use the HTML5 fullscreen API and set the fullscreen to the document or to a specific element.
and after 5 seconds you can use ng-hide to hide the directive.

fullscreen demo page:http://www.fabiobiondi.com/demo/github/angular-fullscreen/demo/